# How to add a New Item form to a page in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, custom-list, wiki-pages

I am using SharePoint Online which looks to be version 2013. I want a New Item form on my home page. I have tried SharePoint Designer 2013. I tried making a new page and it complains that "this page does not contain any areas that are editable in safe mode".

What approach am I supposed to take to accomplish this? I don't need step by step instructions -- just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK There is no "Clicks and Done" way. If you know sharepoint desinger.

1. Open your home page in SPD
2. Insert custom new form webpart in webpart zone
3. Save the page

Please see if below mentioned links help

1. [Display New Form of a List in a Web Part page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70287/display-new-form-of-a-list-in-a-web-part-page)
2. https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105

Comment: I know it isn't constructive to say so but I really hate SPD.

Comment: There is no need to write a code..(Unless you want something more than this form offers).. Its just a click and done way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The New Item page is associated with a list. If all you want is to add items to a list from home page, then you can edit the page and the given list as List View webpart to the page. You will now be able to add items to the list from the home page. However, if you want to actually create a form and with a submit button, Then you will have to use client object model code in the designer to add items to a list on button click.

Comment: I would have to recreate the entire form myself? Because if so, then there is really no point to using SharePoint -- at least for me. I will probably end up using ASP.NET in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but here's an option for modern SharePoint online using modern pages:

You can also create a custom iFrame using the following template, making sure to set custom values for the following elements:

- id: create a unique ID for the form
- src: set this to the URL Of the New Item or Edit Item form page.

Here is the iFrame code template that you can modify and insert:

```
<iframe
width="100%"
height="100%"
id="<make this a unique ID name for the iFrame>"
title="Form "
onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"
allowtransparency="true"
allowfullscreen="true"
allow="geolocation; microphone; camera"
src="https://<link to your sharepoint new item or edit item form>"
frameborder="0"
style="
min-width: 100%;
height:800px;
border:none;"
scrolling="no"
>
</iframe>
```

You can also edit some of the other elements in the iFrame as needed, but ID and SRC are probably the most important.

Then just plug this code into the page as an embedded iFrame like any other. This allows you to embed the form into the page along with other content on that page.